# What purpose does googles server serve?

Tags: google-beacon-platform

So I'm looking at the specs and documentation, looks like everything is exactly as I expect it, but it looks like the beacon API requires registration with googles servers. I don't quite get what the purpose of googles servers are?

I'd like to be able to toss a few beacons with snippets of data, or even just a unique identifier I can use to tie to other stuff, and subscribe to proximity alerts.

I'm GUESSING it has to do with filtering beacons you want nothing to do with, but still seems like if I had an explicit app listening for beacons it recognizes, googles servers would need no place in my infrastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Google servers to filter for specific Eddystone beacons.  The open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) lets you do exactly that without any backend servers using a `Region` filter that can look for beacons with a specific Eddystone namespace id (and optionally an instance id)  like this:

```
// Configure to search for only a single Eddystone
// with a specific namespace Id and instance Id
// You can leave the instance Id null to find all 
// beacons with a given namespace Id.
Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = Identifier.parse("0x2f234454f4911ba9ffa6");
Identifier myBeaconInstanceId = Identifier.parse("0x000000000001");
Region region = new Region("my-beacon-region", myBeaconNamespaceId, myBeaconInstanceId, null);
mBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(this);
try {
   mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can see a full example of this [here.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html)

While you don't need the Google server platform to filter beacons, you can use it to:

1. Tie metadata to your beacons, that can be accessed by apps that detect them.  These could be your own apps or apps owned by others that have access to your beacons.
2. Integrate with other Google services like Nearby or Google Now.

Answer (score 1):

Many companies that start to work with beacons will have to write a few key pieces of software:

1. A table or database somewhere mapping beacons to a location, and possibly some other meta-data as well (Bus Stop 123, or Cash-counter at Store #58133)
2. Some sort of API that allows apps to fetch that meta-data when a beacon is seen — the app just saw Beacon 238925823, now it knows it's very near to Bus Stop 123.
3. It's also nice to be able to go through and see if any of my beacons have dying batteries, etc.

The Proximity Beacon API is basically meant to solve these sorts of problems. It's not necessary to use it, but it's there for those who don't want to implement all this themselves. As a bonus, as stated by [@davidgyoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461050/davidgyoung) above, you can also integrate with other Google services.